# Can't Connect to Minecraft Server When Remote Debugging With IntelliJ

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, minecraft, remote-debugging

The remote debugging is working, but when I have IntelliJ open and the remote debugging profile active, I'm not able to join the Minecraft server with my actual player at all (via localhost). When connecting, it simply says "Disconnected" and shows nothing in the console. I can, however, join the server before loading IntelliJ and using Remote JVM Debug afterwards but when I disconnect, I'm not able to log in again (other servers work fine). The server will not poll after IntelliJ has launched with the profile active (doesn't have to be debugging). I see no other errors anywhere.

Here's what I've tried:

- Running JDK19 on server and client
- Switching ports and using 127.0.0.1 instead
- Using JAR Application configuration
- Using Remote JVM Debug configuration
- Disabling MacOS Firewall (since been re-enabled)

Other stuff I copied... might be useful:

IntelliJ Versions:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3 (Community Edition)
Runtime version: 17.0.5+1-b653.14 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
```

Server Info/Device Info:

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:55637', transport: 'socket'
Starting org.bukkit.craftbukkit.Main
System Info: Java 19 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 19.0.1+10-21) Host: Mac OS X 13.1 (aarch64)
2023-01-28 16:21:45,022 ServerMain WARN Advanced terminal features are not available in this environment
```

Server Version:

```
[16:21:49 INFO]: This server is running Paper version git-Paper-381 (MC: 1.19.3) (Implementing API version 1.19.3-R0.1-SNAPSHOT) (Git: 42fecd0)
```

Minecraft Client Log:

```
[15:32:04] [Render thread/INFO]: Connecting to localhost, 25565
[15:32:13] [Render thread/INFO]: Connecting to localhost, 25565
[15:33:29] [Render thread/INFO]: Connecting to localhost, 25565
```

Answer (score 1):

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUkrH.png)

I figured it out. For whatever reason, the "built-in server debugger" was already set to 25565. Not sure if I set that, but changing it to 25560 fixed the problem!

Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Debugger...Built-in Server